# Intellij - Unable to clone the repository "Clone Failed - Unable to access '<<repo url >> ': Recv failure: Connection was reset

Tags: intellij-idea, repository, clone

I am trying to clone a repository using IntelliJ. I am very new to IntelliJ. I am able to clone the repository using eclipse though.
In eclipse (Git Repositories view), I am asked to provide credentials to access company's GIT Server but not sure where to provide these in Intelli J. I know I can login to GitHub account through IntelliJ but I am trying to access the repo which is in company's GIT server.

Please point out what wrong I am doing and guide me.

In IntelliJ, these are steps I am following.

1. Go for **File** -> **New** -> **Project from Version Control**
2. Select **Repository URL** and enter the values for fields **URL** and **Directory**. Click on **Clone**.

[image]

Here's the error snapshot

[image]

Comment: Adding 2 more points. a. Using the latest community edition of IntelliJ  b. Able to access the GIT repository URL in browser

Comment: Please check whether you have "Use credential helper" enabled under Preferences | Version Control | Git - if so, it may store bad credentials that do not allow you to connect.
Is there a chance that you are using some sort of proxy? Does it work correctly in command-line? IDE relies on command-line git and if it works there, then IDE should work as well

Comment: You were spot on Ruslan.                                                                                                      1. Clone command was not working through command line also                                       2. Found HTTPS_PROXY set in environment variables. Removed it.                                      3. Unchecked "Use Credential Helper" in IntelliJ                                                                         After the above steps, I was able to clone through Intelli J. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For future references to anyone having this same problem, copying the code url instead of ssh from github would solve this issue.

Comment: In my case the clone was successful, but the same error came up. I opened another project and then opened the "failed" project and everything is fine.